# How to make multiple threads output to the same console line in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I want To run all the 3 threads main , t1 and t2. Their output should all go to the same console line.

They Run At Same time but there is some line difference between the print please tell me how can i print all these 3 threads in same line continously

```
        mytask mt = new mytask();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mt.code2));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mt.code3));

        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Current Thread";
        t1.Name = "Code 2";
        t2.Name = "Code 3";
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Name + "\t\t"+ t1.Name+"\t\t"+Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t" + i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

class mytask
{
    public void Code2()
    {
                for (int k = 0; k < 60; k++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t" + i + " : " + j + " :" + k);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
          }
    public void code3()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 60; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with run in the same line?

Comment: i mean they should appear in same line on the console window side by side as in they are in rows and columns

Comment: and why you need this in different threads?

Comment: Thats the task ..I Know it can be done in same thread or in same console.writeline

Comment: Is this homework?  Because if you have to interleave the results in order anyway, you're going to be far better off just doing this synchronously.

Comment: Typically what you do is have one thread (probably the main thread in this case) get information from the other two threads and output it. That way only one thread is actually writing to the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to all appear on one line, use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.  It won't add a newline each time.